# XML ENTITY in attribute

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, xsd, attributes, xsd-validation

I have an XML document with images as external entities. However, I am unable to resolve them in an attribute:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE catalog [
    <!NOTATION jpg SYSTEM "image/jpg">
    <!ENTITY su.jpg SYSTEM "su.jpg" NDATA jpg>
]>
<catalog>
...
    <image src="su.jpg" />
...

</catalog>
```

Here is the relevant part of my XML Schema:

```xml
...
<xs:element name="image">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:ENTITY" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...
```

I get the following error in Visual Studio Code:
`The value 'su.jpg' of attribute 'src' on element 'image' is not valid with respect to its type, 'ENTITY'.xml(cvc-attribute.3)`
Obviously, if I change the attribute type to `xs:string`, everything will be fine. However, I can't do this because my project requires binary data to be an entity in the XML document.

Comment: I don't see much of a difference to the example given in "Example 11-7. Using an unparsed entity" at http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter11.html. It is certainly possible to use an entity in an attribute.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I also found a source, showing the exact same use. The XML document shows up just fine in all browsers and all online XML validators claim it's OK. Still, it bothers me.